# Save image as blob or convert to actual image

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where I'm creating lots, (potentially x,000,000s) of images.

When they are created, they are created on the fly and are blobs. e.g.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAO... etc
```

Is it safe and efficient to save them as they are in MySQL or would you recommend saving them as actual images in a directory then storing just the path? And why?

Completely new to me this so kind of a general question. I'm using PHP and MySQL db.

Comment: if you store the path in a db, you still have to make a call to the db to get the path. might as well store the entire image there.

Comment: The pros and cons of both approaches have been discussed ad nauseam.

Comment: Nobody but you can tell. Saving them as base64 definitely wastes some 2 of 8 bits. If you store them in the DB, you automatically get backups whenever the DB is backed up, but it will get harder to move a full DB backup around, so that speaks for using files. Really your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all the files in a directory you will have to deal with the limitations of the filesystem(s). A huge number of files can be a problem for some filesystems (i.e. FAT32)

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'd use FAT32 on a server though.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Anything on Windows Server 2003 + uses NTFS, and Linux... The range of File Systems available, It's unlikley you would touch FAT32 (last I checked, this FS was supported by most Linux)

Comment: I can't even think of the last time I saw FAT32 other than SD Cards/Memory Sticks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like messing around with two saves (blob and path) is double work.  Just save as image in the most efficient pic format possible.

However, an earlier answer indicates this issue has been discussed many times before; just refer to those discussions.